# dynamic controls and events issue with post back

Tags: c#, asp.net

here's my page's life story

first: there's a button (linkButton if that matters) and its onClick action-1   (event set in Page_Load)

that action makes a panel get visible

the now-visible panel contains not-Dynamic controls ; a button and its onclick action-2

action-2 adds the dynamic controls (table&row&cell ,radioButtonList )

what I wanted to do is to get the selected item of each radioButtonList that has been generated !!

and here's what I tried doing :

tryout-1 {`radioButtonList1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler (function);`} ->failed , I don't know why event won't fire!!!

tryout-2 {

```
foreach (Control x in radioButtonList1.Controls)
{RadioButton one = (RadioButton)x;
one.CheckedChanged += new Eventhandler(function);} -> failed .. won't fire O.o
```

}

tryout-3 I added a button(plus onClick event) along with each radioButtonList so I can get the selected item when the button is clicked .. but it failed as well ; when the button is clicked the dynamically created controls are gone

I know there's "IsPostBack"thing , but as far as I know it should be in Page_Load|Init and my controls are generated in an event action !! am I mistaken??

and now after more than 2 days of work I'm still in square 1 , and I ran out of games to play around this

any idea what to do ?!
PS :  I did the story-like post cuz I don't know what code to post .. it's mostly objects declaration !! so, if u need a particular piece of code let me know and I'll post it

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You must set PostBack to true for radio button.

Comment: katri the AutoPostBack u mean ?? what about the other controls like table&row&cell ?? or just the controls with events?!